# MySQL: Retrieving ID where exactly 2 rows share the same ID but have different userIDs

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that associates a user to a conversation that looks like the following image or sqlfiddle:

[MySQL Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEjLM.png)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4d329

As you can see, user 1000001 and user 1000002 both belong to 2 conversations - 10 and 20.

What I need to do is retrieve the conversation_id where only users 1000001 and user 1000002 are associated with it. The correct conversation_id that would be pulled is 10.

As you can see with conversation_id 20, a 3rd user is associated with it - 1000003 - so I don't want to pull that conversation_id, even though users 1000001 and 1000002 are associated with it.

Also note that the scenario can't happen when only one user_id is associated with a conversation_id.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: instead of posting a screenshot, why not provide a minimal, verifiable example on sql fiddle?

Comment: No pictures, thanks. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I provided a sqlfiddle.

Comment: So what should happen when only one user is connected to a conversation ? Should we still get that conversation Or, we should get only those conversations where both users exist and only they exist

Comment: Sorry Madhur, I edited my post to say that it's not possible for only 1 user to be connected to a conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a performant approach, using no subqueries at all. You can simply filter out results in `Having` clause, using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  conversation_id 
FROM assoc_user__conversation 
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING 
  -- all the rows to exists only for 1000001 or 1000002 only
  SUM(user_id IN (1000001, 1000002)) = COUNT(*)
```

**Result**

```
| conversation_id |
| --------------- |
| 10              |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sQgn9Q8JLHZcmjtMVBc5to/1)

---

Another variation of conditional aggregation possible is:

```
SELECT 
  conversation_id 
FROM assoc_user__conversation 
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING 
  -- atleast one row for 1000001 to exists
  SUM(user_id = 1000001) AND  
  -- atleast one row for 1000002 to exists
  SUM(user_id = 1000002) AND  
  -- no row to exist for other user_id values
  NOT SUM(user_id NOT IN (1000001, 1000002))
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that every conversation has at least 2 participants, we can remove all conversations where someone else is there, leaving us with conversations in which only these 2 users are present.

Note: We need the above assumption because there might be cases where `1000001` is the only participant and we do not want to show those conversations.

```
select conversation_id
from table
where conversation_id not in (
    select conversation_id 
    from table 
    where user_id not in (1000001, 1000002))
```

**Edit:**

If it's possible that only one user_id is associated with a conversation_id, we can remove those conversations too.

```
select conversation_id
from table
where conversation_id not in (
    select conversation_id 
    from table 
    where user_id not in (1000001, 1000002))
group by conversation_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Assuming that same user_id won't be in the same conversation twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sahil. However, the scenario will exist when only one user_id is associated with a conversation_id.

Comment: @SahilDhoked Thanks for the suggested edit on my answer. but it is really not required. The trick involved is `SUM(...)` will return either 0 or 1 (because of comparison conditions inside), and MySQL will simply use  0 or 1 as boolean

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but I'm pretty sure it is logically sound.  You didn't say the name of the table so I just called it table.

```
select conversation_id from (
  select conversation_id, count(*) as count, t1.user_id as user_1, t2.user_id as user_2 
  from table t1
  join table t2 on (t1.conversation_id = t2.conversation_id and t1.user_id != t2.user_id)
  where t1.user_id = 1000001 and
  t2.user_id = 1000002
) as inner_table
where inner_table.count = 2
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't :-(

Comment: This answer actually does work with the proper aliases. Sahil's answer also works but I'd like to see if any more answers come in first before selecting a correct answer, to see which one people think is best, performance wise:    SELECT inner_table.conversation_id FROM (SELECT t1.conversation_id, COUNT(*) as count, t1.user_id AS user_1, t2.user_id AS user_2 FROM assoc_user__conversation t1 JOIN assoc_user__conversation t2 ON (t1.conversation_id = t2.conversation_id and t1.user_id != t2.user_id) WHERE t1.user_id = 1000001 AND t2.user_id = 1000002) AS inner_table WHERE inner_table.count = 2

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to your answer about the "sound" logic used. All I see is multiple convoluted subqueries. Also note that `table` is [Reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-T). You should avoid using it as table/column name, even in the examples; or use backticks around it. Please fix these syntax errors.