# MySQL: Retrieve ID where x number of user_ids associated with it

Tags: mysql

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

I have a MySQL table that looks like the following DB Fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xa2Dt9cAPhiMfHcEv8Lifo/0

What I need to do is retrieve the conversation_id where I can specify the user_ids associated with it, and retrieve the conversation_id associated with exactly those user_ids.

First example: say I wanted to get the conversation_id where only users 1000001 and 1000002 are associated with it. The correct conversation_id that would be pulled is 10.

Second example: say I wanted to get the conversation_id where only users 1000001, 1000002 and 1000003 are associated with it. The correct conversation_id that would be pulled is 20.

...and so on.

Also note that the scenario can't happen when only one user_id is associated with a conversation_id.

I posted my first question here, but realized later that I need to be able to pull a conversation_id where 2 or more (up to 16) specified user_ids are associated with it: [MySQL: Retrieving ID where exactly 2 rows share the same ID but have different userIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124760/mysql-retrieving-id-where-exactly-2-rows-share-the-same-id-but-have-different-u)

One of the answers I received is this which can work for 2 or more user_ids by specifying the user_ids in the IN clause, and then putting the total amount of users into the COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) clause. However it seems to be the slowest answer performance wise and only seems to use the conversation_id key in EXPLAIN when user_id_2 key is a possible key (contains conversation_id and user_id).

```
SELECT 
  conversation_id 
FROM assoc_user__conversation 
GROUP BY conversation_id 
HAVING 
  -- all the rows to exists only for 1000001 or 1000002 only
  SUM(user_id IN (1000001, 1000002)) = COUNT(*) AND 
  -- number of unique user_id is 2
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, user_id int  NOT NULL
, conversation_id int NOT NULL
, UNIQUE(user_id,conversation_id)
, INDEX(conversation_id,user_id)  
);

INSERT INTO my_table (id, user_id, conversation_id) VALUES
(1, 1, 10),
(2, 2, 10),
(3, 1, 20),
(4, 2, 20),
(5, 3, 20),
(6, 1, 30),
(7, 2, 30),
(8, 3, 30),
(9, 4, 30);

SELECT x.conversation_id
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.conversation_id = x.conversation_id
   AND y.user_id NOT IN(1,2)
 WHERE x.user_id IN (1,2)
   AND y.id IS NULL
 GROUP
    BY x.conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
+-----------------+
| conversation_id |
+-----------------+
|              10 |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @Strawberry. I marked it as correct. I put over 2.7 million rows in the table and the query executed in 0.01 seconds whereas the query I provided in the question executes at over 7.3 seconds! Thanks again :)

Comment: @PHPMYSQLDEV I'm impressed at those statistics. I think you must be running on considerably better hardware than me!

Comment: Presumably you have an index on conversation_id,user_id ?? - I've edited the answer to emphasise this requirement...

Comment: Yes, @Strawberry, actually I'm a simple shared server for the moment while I build :)  Yes there's an index on both user_id and conversation_id